# Calculate rolling sum of an array in PySpark using Window()?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I want to calculate a rolling sum of an ArrayType column given a unix timestamp and group it by 2 second increments. Example input/output is below. I think the Window() function will work, I'm pretty new to PySpark and am totally lost. Any input is greatly appreciated!

Input:

```
timestamp     vars 
2             [1,2,1,2]
2             [1,2,1,2]
3             [1,1,1,2]
4             [1,3,4,2]
5             [1,1,1,3]
6             [1,2,3,5]
9             [1,2,3,5]
```

Expected output:

```
+---------+-----------------------+
|timestamp|vars                   |
+---------+-----------------------+
|2        |[2.0, 4.0, 2.0, 4.0]   |
|4        |[4.0, 8.0, 7.0, 8.0]   |
|6        |[6.0, 11.0, 11.0, 16.0]|
|10       |[7.0, 13.0, 14.0, 21.0]|
+---------+-----------------------+
```

Thanks!

Edit:  Multiple columns can have the same timestamp/they might not be consecutive. The length of vars may also be > 3. Looking for a slightly generic solution please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sum` window function to compute the running sum and `row_number` to pick every second timestamp row.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
w = Window.orderBy(col('timestamp'))
result = df.withColumn('summed_vars',array([sum(col('vars')[i]).over(w) for i in range(3)])) #change the value 3 as desired
result.filter(col('rnum')%2 == 0).select('timestamp','summed_vars').show()
```

Change the `%2` as needed per your time interval.

Edit: Grouping by time intervals with [`window`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.window). Assuming `timestamp` column is of data type `timestamp`.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import window,sum,row_number,array,col 
w = Window.orderBy(col('timestamp'))
result = df.withColumn('timestamp_interval',window(col('timestamp'),'2 second')) \
           .withColumn('summed_vars',array(*[sum(col('vars')[i]).over(w) for i in range(4)])) 
w1 = Window.partitionBy(col('timestamp_interval')).orderBy(col('timestamp').desc())
final_result = result.withColumn('rnum',row_number().over(w1))
final_result.filter(col('rnum')==1).drop(*['rnum','vars']).show()
```

Comment: What if there are multiple columns with the same timestamp or timestamp isn't unique? This also needs to be flexible to work for different length input (not just array of length 3) and different time intervals (like 1 hour). Could you please help make this more generic?

Comment: you should add all these details to the question, not after getting an answer.

Comment: Updated. Thanks!

Comment: what's the desired behavior when there are multiple rows with the same timestamp? can you demonstrate with an example?

Comment: Filtering by `col('rnum')%2 == 0` will not work if `timestamp` values start by 2 and not 1 for example.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala That's what I'm saying :). Just remove the first row with `timestamp = 1` and test it.

Comment: you mean *if consecutive rows differ by more than 1*

Comment: @Vamsi Prabhala Consecutive rows could differ by more than 1, and if there are duplicate timestamps, we want to include them in thr running total. I'll update thr question with an example.

Answer (score 2):

For Spark 2.4+ you can use array functions and higher-order functions. This solution will work for different array sizes (event if different between each row). Here are the steps explained:

First, group by 2 seconds and collect the `vars` in an array column :

```
df = df.groupBy((ceil(col("timestamp") / 2) * 2).alias("timestamp")) \
       .agg(collect_list(col("vars")).alias("vars"))

df.show()

#+---------+----------------------+
#|timestamp|vars                  |
#+---------+----------------------+
#|6        |[[1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3]]|
#|2        |[[1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1]]|
#|4        |[[1, 1, 1], [1, 3, 4]]|
#+---------+----------------------+
```

Here we grouped each consecutive 2 seconds and collected the `vars` arrays into a new list. 
Now, using a Window spec you can collect cumulative values and use [`flatten`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#flatten) to flatten the sub arrays:

```
w = Window.orderBy("timestamp").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
df = df.withColumn("vars", flatten(collect_list(col("vars")).over(w)))
df.show()

#+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|timestamp|vars                                                              |
#+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|2        |[[1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1]]                                            |
#|4        |[[1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 3, 4]]                      |
#|6        |[[1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 3, 4], [1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3]]|
#+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Finally, use [`aggregate`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#aggregate) function with [`zip_with`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#zip_with) to sum the arrays :

```
t = "aggregate(vars, cast(array() as array<double>), (acc, a) -> zip_with(acc, a, (x, y) -> coalesce(x, 0) + coalesce(y, 0)))"

df.withColumn("vars", expr(t)).show(truncate=False)

#+---------+-----------------+
#|timestamp|vars             |
#+---------+-----------------+
#|2        |[2.0, 3.0, 2.0]  |
#|4        |[4.0, 7.0, 7.0]  |
#|6        |[6.0, 10.0, 11.0]|
#+---------+-----------------+
```

Putting all together:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import ceil, col, collect_list, flatten, expr
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.orderBy("timestamp").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
t = "aggregate(vars, cast(array() as array<double>), (acc, a) -> zip_with(acc, a, (x, y) -> coalesce(x, 0) + coalesce(y, 0)))"

nb_seconds = 2

df.groupBy((ceil(col("timestamp") / nb_seconds) * nb_seconds).alias("timestamp")) \
  .agg(collect_list(col("vars")).alias("vars")) \
  .withColumn("vars", flatten(collect_list(col("vars")).over(w))) \
  .withColumn("vars", expr(t)).show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: using aggregate with the zip in the expression was a sound way of bringing it all together. nice answer

Comment: Thank you! Could you help me understand how to make this more generic for lists > 3 or for not every 2 seconds. What if I wanted to group for every 5 seconds or even hour?

Comment: @justneedsomehelppls it will work also for lists > 3 and you can set the number of seconds you want to group by as in the code `nb_seconds = 2`.

Comment: the collected *number* of arrays with `collect_list` might get too big.

Comment: This is super helpful. Thank you! My only concern is that each individual list can be up to 1 million in length, so this can get expensive. Not sure how scalable this solution is.